# Character controller collides unusally... Help me to fix it

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I am making a infinty runner game, I am very beginner for making that. My character collides with objects without touching it, and i am using character controller. This is my player movement script,

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    private CharacterController controller;
    public float forwardSpeed;
    private Vector3 direction;

    private int desiredLane = 1;//0:left, 1:middle, 2:right
    public float laneDistance = 2.5f;//The distance between tow lanes
    public Animator animator;


    private bool isGrounded;

    private void Start()
    {
        controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        direction.z = forwardSpeed;

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow))
        {
            print("Right");
            desiredLane++;
            if(desiredLane == 3)
            {
                desiredLane = 2;
            }
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
        {
            print("Left");
            desiredLane--;
            if (desiredLane == -1)
            {
                desiredLane = 0;
            }
        }

        //future position

        Vector3 targetPostion = transform.position.z * transform.forward + transform.position.y * transform.up;

        if (desiredLane == 0)
        {
            targetPostion += Vector3.left * laneDistance;
        }else if(desiredLane ==2) {
            targetPostion += Vector3.right * laneDistance;

        }

        transform.position = targetPostion;
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        controller.Move(direction * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

I want fix the problem, The charachter controller collides too much.

Comment: First of all what is this about `transform.position = targetPostion;` ? This completely bypasses any CharacterConroller / Physics in the scene ...